# Cisco Switchport mode by SNMP

Tags: perl, snmp, cisco

Do it have a way to access and add/change/remove the switchport mode option from a port by SNMP ?

I found no any information about it and seems to be not possible...

I'm curently searching a way to autoconfig ports using perl scripts and SNMP.

If anyone have a solution or even another way to do this, I'll be grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your post is, that you want to configure the vlans and trunks (or something else?) on multiple switches/routers . If thats true you better look on "VLAN Trunking Protocol". One of the best guides and explanation I found is that one- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHw7OUqcg-g

The best way would probably be to prepare individual configuration and extract it via Console.

Otherwise I am still confuse what you really want to achieve. If they have IP assigned to a vlan/interface you can burst configuration via Telnet with a script. - But that looks like an overkill for this purpose.

Comment: No, I just want to enable switchport mode access on port from snmp, my purpose is to activate cisco port security but the switchport mode acces have to be set for that.